# Should i add a hreflang tag for all the different urls that point to the same localized page?

Tags: hreflang

I have a plant guide page that can be accessed from multiple urls. This plant guide page can be in multiple languages. Should i add a hreflang tag for each alternative url or just one of them? For instance the canonical one?

Comment: Are the different URLs just for different languages, or are there URL variations for other reasons such as www/no-www, http/https, index.html/no-index.html, etc?

Comment: The latter @StephenOstermiller. Each plant guide is about one plant variety. For instance the scottisch bonnet pepper. This variety goes by different names and the variety name is always included in the last path segment of the url. When a plant variety has multiple variety names it also can have multiple urls pointing to the same page